# How do I select a specific date OR the latest date if the specific date doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table of employee assignment START_DATEs and STOP_DATEs. Employees only have one assignment at a time, so after one assignment stops another begins eventually. Assignments that are still in progress have a STOP_DATE represented as the minimum datetime, '1753-01-01'. Something like this:

| EMPLOYEE | START_DATE | STOP_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | 2023-07-05 | 2023-07-06 |
| 51 | 2023-07-07 | 2023-07-10 |
| 51 | 2023-07-11 | 1753-01-01 |
| 32 | 2023-07-04 | 2023-07-06 |
| 32 | 2023-07-06 | 2023-07-07 |
| 32 | 2023-07-11 | 2023-07-12 |

I'm trying to filter the table to show me all the latest assignments. In other words, I'm trying to get all employee assignments that are currently in progress (STOP_DATE '1753-01-01'), or, if they don't have any assignments that are currently in progress, to get the assignment with the latest STOP_DATE:

| EMPLOYEE | STOP_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | 1753-01-01 |
| 32 | 2023-07-12 |

I can use a ROW_NUMBER/PARTITION BY to isolate the latest stop date, but figuring out how to *ignore* an employee's latest stop date if they have a stop date of 1753-01-01 somewhere is giving me trouble.

Comment: `ORDER BY IIF(STOP_DATE = '17530101', '99990101' STOP_DATE) DESC` essentially you should have used the max value not the min value.

Comment: The decision to set STOP_DATE to a *past* date (`DATE '1753-01-01'`) when there is no stop date yet is rare. One would rather just leave it NULL or put in some *future* date like `DATE '2999-31-12'`. But you can just work with the start date instead as shown in Eric's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think just a simple `ROW_NUMBER()` should do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY START_DATE DESC) AS rn
    FROM SomeTable
)t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: That assumes the `START_DATE` is strictly monotonic from a previous `END_DATE` with no overlap. Otherwise the results are not the same.

Comment: @Charlieface OP's word, "Employees only have one assignment at a time, so after one assignment stops another begins eventually"

Answer (score 0):

Windowed functions to the rescue!

```
SELECT Employee, StartDate, StopDate
  FROM (
        SELECT *, MAX(StopDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee) AS mxStopDate, MIN(StopDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee) AS mnStopDate
          FROM @Table
       ) a
 WHERE StopDate = '1753-01-01'
    OR (StopDate = mxStopDate AND mnStopDate <> '1753-01-01')
```

Here we're using MIN and MAX windowed functions to find the first and last stop dates for each employee. Since we can't reference them in the where clause, we're using them as a subquery, and filtering on the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit meaningless to show a date in 1753 as indicating something is in progress - just a NULL here would be preferable since it doesn't have a stop date yet.

Based on your description it would make more sense to just aggregate as follows and just indicate it's *actually* in progress:

```
select Employee, 
  Max(Iif(Stop_date = '17530101', 'In Progress', Convert(Varchar(10), Stop_Date, 120)))
from Assignments
group by employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be safe and sufficiently fast, assuming you have an index on `(Employee, StopDate)`:

```sql
declare @t table (
    Employee int,
    StartDate date,
    StopDate date
);

-- Sample data
insert into @t (Employee, StartDate, StopDate)
values
(51, '2023-07-05', '2023-07-06'),
(51, '2023-07-07', '2023-07-10'),
(51, '2023-07-11', '1753-01-01'),
(32, '2023-07-04', '2023-07-06'),
(32, '2023-07-06', '2023-07-07'),
(32, '2023-07-11', '2023-07-12');

-- The query
select sq.Employee, sq.StopDate
from (
select t.Employee, t.StopDate,
    row_number() over(
        partition by t.Employee
        order by case t.StopDate
            when '17530101' then 1
            else 2
        end, t.StopDate desc
    ) as [RN]
from @t t
) sq
where sq.RN = 1;
```